# Spark progress monitoring in dsx lost after changing spark configuration parameters

Tags: data-science-experience

What is the recommended way to turn on Spark speculation in a DSX notebook?  We have a way that works but we no longer see the Spark progress being shown in the notebook, e.g., the number of tasks that have complete so far.

Here is what we do: [image: DSX notebook example]

We checked the icon for enabling/disabling Spark progress monitoring and it is already enabled.  Any tips?  Thanks!

Comment: You're creating a new SparkContext, instead of using the predefined one. This has lead to other problems in the past. But since you're trying to enable some non-default settings, I can't see an alternative.

Comment: @RolandWeber is there a way for us to update the conf without starting a new context?

Comment: None that I would like to recommend for users.